# PHP Code Cleaning

Tags: php, mysql

Am running the following code to gather some data from my page and store it in my database, however, i need to add some extra functionality to it but i don't seem to be able to do it correctly.

The Code:

```
// Get Referrer and Page
if (isset($_GET["ref"])) 
{
// from javascript
$referer = $_GET["ref"];
$page = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? (parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH)) : (''));  
} 
else 
{
// from php
$referer = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) ? ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) : (''));
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // with include via php       
} 

// Cleanup
if (basename($page) == basename(__FILE__)) $page = "" ;
```

This script is storing $page as "/site/index.php or /site/about.php", for example. I kinda want it to store it as "Index or About" without the whole /site/ and .php part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nothing to do with PHP - it's about how the webserver maps URLs to files and you didn't say what webserver this is. If it's Apache, have a look at mod_rewrite

Comment: Are you just looking for a regular expression to strip out the directory and suffix?

Comment: am looking for something like basename($page, ".php"), which should output it as just index, stripping the .php tag from it. And yes, it's an Apache server.

Comment: Interestingly the question is not about "code cleaning", or mysql or basename. So I'm curious about your choice of title and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php), for example:

```
<?php
$page = "/site/index.php";
$page_info = pathinfo($page);
$page_name = $page_info['filename'];
echo $page_name; //output: index
?>
```